# Make a jQuery library init a DatePicker on-demand and destroy when done with it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have been testing a good 10+ jQuery DatePicker libraries over the past month for use in my app.  They all have things I like and dislike for my particular use.

Really what I want is super lightweight as part of my app simply needs to allow a user to pick a date and save it using AJAX post.  I then reload/update the Date value over and over again on the same element as different task records are loaded into a Modal window.

Most all the libraries work for that functionality as I am simply using 1 instance of the DatePicker.

My concern now is on another screen in my app which will have a DatePicker attached to a filed for every editable Task record on the screen.  There could be up to 200 DatePickers on a screen!

For this reason I would like to instead have a DatePicker library that allows me to initialize the DatePicker on-demand when the date value is clicked on by the user.  So of 200 DatePicker Date fields, a user clicks to change one of them and the DatePicker will at that point be initialized and allow the user to pick the date.  When they are done it will save using AJAX and close the DatePicker also destroying it!

SO the key here is a library that works as normal but allows for on-demand init and destroy when done.  This allows any number to be on a page but actually will only be a very small amount in use at a time!

As mentioned I have been testing all the popular libraries.  Most of them are 2-3,000 lines of code.  This is not an issue but today I found the older **Bootstrap DatePicker library** here http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ and was very happy to see that it actually does not even require the Bootstrap library to be loaded and it is only 432 lines opf code and works great!  It has an `onChange` callback for allowing my AJAX save and also some set date functions to allow me to re-use the 1 DatePicker field on my Task Modal.

The thing that is missing though is the ability to init on-demand and destroy when done.

So I would have to add this into it somehow.

So below is a quick demo I setup of the library on a field.  Does any JavaScript experts know how I could go about adding the ability to init on  demand this date picker on several fields as needed and then destroy it on my `onChange` event that is fired?

My demo JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/2etw5ehd/

DatePicker Library Source Code:  https://github.com/Aymkdn/Datepicker-for-Bootstrap/blob/master/bootstrap-datepicker.js

Comment: It sounds like you could of wrote your own with the time you have spent , have you wrote your own plugins before? I would suggest starting with an empty template and building out what you want

Comment: @ScottSelby JavaScript isn't my strongest lang but I am learning a lot and I have deff learned a lot about DatePickers!   Finding this one that is only 400 lines of code and has the same functionality as all the much larger ones is really nice though and if I can add in functionality to init and destroy an instance of it as needed, it will be perfect for me!  I am not sure how to do it yet but with it being this lightweight, I think adding that in would be easier than starting from scratch

Comment: This DatePicker library linked below has the `init on-demand` and `destroy` functionality http://mugifly.github.io/jquery-simple-datetimepicker/jquery.simple-dtpicker.html I might use this library but I would love to get this Bootsrap one in my question above working as it actually works a little better and is more lightweight, as the other one has an anoyying bug in it that changes the selected date when browing dates

Comment: also, don't confuse "light weight" with lines of code , there could be 200k lines of code for events that aren't used and never fire , or for cases that don't match yours.  In that case the extra size of the js file is almost insignificant for page load when minified, and the actual code won't slow things down any bit that can ever be noticed.